# Python for IOS or Android

Tags: android, python, ios, sl4a

I have been looking at the different packages for python on android and IOS as i am going to be upgrading my phone soon.

However, i dont know which OS to go with. For android they have the SL4A package, but for IOS they have their equivilent. However, im stuck on which to go for. Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

I know its kind of a stupid question, however im just getting into mobile development since they allowed scripting languages on the mobile platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been on the lookut for Python on iOS for sometime. About 2-months ago, one one released to the iTunes app store -- http://pythonforios.com/ and it is fantastic!  It includes the complete set of Python 2.7.2 documentation -- which alone is worth the $3 price.

It's a bit of a challenge to code any serious apps (which I suspect is the result of the developer having to comply w/ Apple's app guidelines), but it is a perfect place to test ideas from a train or airport (when you are without a laptop).

1 caveat -- I've only tried it on an iPad. It could be a bit cramped screen real-estate on an iphone.

Comment: are you able to load scripts from your computer into it and run it through the interpreter on the phone? or are you limited to writing and running them through the interpreter on the phone? :)

Comment: Officially you are limited to code, save, run directly on iOS device. But it's a simple matter to download a file from net and execute.  I assume w/ some minor thinking one could rig a git pull/run system that would fit pretty well with code & deployment from someplace more suitable for editing

Comment: alright, thank you very much :) you have answered my question completely. :)

Answer (score 3):

The python support for Android is pretty good, but still under development. You can do things that a scripting language can but not the stuff that Python as a OO language can.

Example:- When you go through the api reference [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference), you can see that one can write scripts to do basic to complex tasks, but, in a restrictive way. You can never build full blown apps, and even if you do, it will always be slow because the SLA4 is just another layer on top of few other layers in the Android hierarchy. There have been a lot of fun stuff that has been done using Python scripting, example: http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/07/nexus-one-phone-rides-a-rocket-up-28000-feet/#ixzz0v7LFT7ay (A bit over-board and crazy, but awesome nonetheless.)

I don't have much experience on an IPhone to pass on such comments. But, an IPhone is expensive. You can always get a used Nexus phone and do all kinds of Python hacking/scripting. All depends on your budget and your need.

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

[Pythonista](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/lisping/id512138518?mt=8) is an excellent alternative for the iOS platform - [here's](http://buff.ly/1oxkEDP) a nice article on it. And [this](http://buff.ly/1oxlFfk) one details how you can achieve workflow automation on the iPAD.